# How to send form input from client to server for external API call in Angular/Express?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, express

I am using Angular to get form input and then the client will make a request to the server which then makes a call to the external API. How can I get the input on the form to be concatenated to the server's API call?

```
  // app.js
  $scope.searchTag = function () {
    var tag = $scope.tag.replace(/\s+/, '');
    var url = 'http://api.com' + tag;
    $http.get('/api')
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        $scope.tag = '';
        $scope.recipes = response.data;
    });
  };

 // server.js
 app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
   request('http://api.com' + ***tag***, function (error, response,) {
     res.json;
   });
 });

 // index.html
 <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" ng-model="tag" class="form-control" placeholder="Let's find some recipes for you" style="width: 240px">
 </div>
```